# Oracle select query for link table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables tbl_Party and Link_Party

```
tbl_Party
Columns
PartyId - uniquekey,
PartyNAme,
sk_party,
```

Link table

```
link_party
Coulmns
PartyId_a,
PartyId_b,
linktype
```

Now Party table will have different partyids.
Some of the parties from the party table could be linked to each other in the link table
Now, I need to wrote a query like

```
select 
  partyid_a,
  sk_party,
  partyid_b,
  sk_party 
from 
  party, 
  link_party
```

Comment: Could you post the table structures? It's a little unclear from your description.

Comment: This is so basic - please just read some sql documentation about `JOIN` and if you're still lost, then ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your table structure correctly then something like the following:

```
SELECT      L.PartyId_a,
            PA.sk_party,
            L.PartyId_b,
            PB.sk_party
FROM        link_party L
INNER JOIN  tbl_Party PA ON L.PartyId_a = PA.PartyId
INNER JOIN  tbl_Party PB ON L.PartyId_b = PB.PartyId
```

Answer (score 0):

Ref [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081331/sql-query-to-match-sellers-and-buyers) you will get some idea

```
SELECT
  a.partyid    AS partyid_a,
  a.sk_party     AS sk_party_a, 
  b.partyid    AS partyid_b,
  b.sk_party     AS sk_party_b, 
FROM
  party              AS a
INNER JOIN
  link_party            AS lp
    ON lp.partyid_a = a.partyid
INNER JOIN
  party              AS b
  ON lp.partyid_b = b.partyid
```