# Cardinality violation on mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Im getting an error on this query:

```
SELECT i.name, i.surname, (SELECT u.username FROM user u WHERE u.info_id IN (1,9,10,15,25,40,42,43,44)) as email FROM `userinfo` i WHERE i.id IN (1,9,10,15,25,40,42,43,44)
```

Error:

> Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row

I know this could be solved by using a JOIN statment but i have no idea how to solve that.

To clarify more my question, I have two tables, user and userinfo:

*User*

```
id info_id username
```

*Userinfo*

```
id name surname
```

The info_id row from `user` is related to the id of `userinfo`, so having a list of userinfo ids in this format (1,4,7,8,9) I want name and surname (from `userinfo`) and username from `user` that match the info_id

Comment: `(SELECT u.username FROM user u WHERE u.info_id IN (1,9,10,15,25,40,42,43,44))` returns more than one item, and cannot be handled.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to specify the relationship between the two table in the correlated subquery,

```
SELECT  i.name, 
        i.surname, 
        (
            SELECT  u.username 
            FROM    user u 
            WHERE   u.info_id = i.id) as email 
FROM    userinfo i 
WHERE   i.id IN (1,9,10,15,25,40,42,43,44)
```

and by using `JOIN` (*which I preferred more*)

```
SELECT  i.name, 
        i.surname, 
        u.username as Email
FROM    userinfo i 
        INNER JOIN user u 
            ON u.info_id = i.id
WHERE   i.id IN (1,9,10,15,25,40,42,43,44)
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Why do you prefer the `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: @BSeven [ANSI vs. non-ANSI SQL JOIN syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599050/ansi-vs-non-ansi-sql-join-syntax)

Answer (score 2):

You're only allowed to return one row in a field list.  It seems like you want to group the results.

```
SELECT
    i.name, i.surname,
    GROUP_CONCAT(u.username) AS email
FROM
    userinfo i
    JOIN user u ON (i.id = u.info_id)
WHERE
    i.id IN (1,9,10,15,25,40,42,43,44)
GROUP BY
    i.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT i.name, i.surname, u.username as email 
FROM `userinfo` i 
     INNER JOIN
     `user` u ON i.info_id=u.id
WHERE i.id IN (1,9,10,15,25,40,42,43,44)
```

Learn to use joins, without them you are working wit both hands tied behind your back AND blindfolded. Joins are how to use the Relational part of Relational Databases.

Comment: The most compact yet readable, and the fact of not knowing Joins is *working with both hands tied behind your back* too.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
SELECT i.name, i.surname, (SELECT u.username FROM user u WHERE u.id IN (1,9,10,15,25,40,42,43,44)) as email

FROM `userinfo` i

WHERE i.id IN (1,9,10,15,25,40,42,43,44)
```