# SQL Query Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, msg

I'm stuck to this error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Column 'Subjects.off_CODE' is
>   invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I don't know what is wrong with this query.

```
use Enlistment
go

SELECT Subjects.off_CODE, Subjects.subj_CODE, Subjects.description, 
Subjects.unit, COUNT(Enlistment.off_CODE) FROM Enlistment, Subjects
WHERE Subjects.off_CODE = 11315
GROUP BY Enlistment.off_CODE
```

Comment: I think so you are using MSSQL..  You need to use all the columns other than the aggregate one in the group by clause.. So your group by clause will be `GROUP BY Subjects.off_CODE, Subjects.subj_CODE, Subjects.description, 
Subjects.unit`

Comment: Are you aware that you are performing a cartesian product between your tables?

Comment: Please consider using ansi syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599050/ansi-vs-non-ansi-sql-join-syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column is selected, it must appear in the GROUP BY clause, unless it is contained in an aggregate function (just like the error message says).

```
use Enlistment
go

SELECT Subjects.off_CODE, Subjects.subj_CODE, Subjects.description, 
Subjects.unit, COUNT(Enlistment.off_CODE) FROM Enlistment, Subjects
WHERE Subjects.off_CODE = 11315
GROUP BY Subjects.off_CODE, Subjects.subj_CODE, Subjects.description, 
Subjects.unit
```

So, in your example, the only field that is selected that does not have to be included in the GROUP BY clause is **Enlistment.off_CODE** because it is used in the aggregate function COUNT (**COUNT(Enlistment.off_CODE)**). All of the other fields must be included in the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
GROUP BY Enlistment.off_CODE, Subjects.off_CODE
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT Subjects.off_CODE, Subjects.subj_CODE, Subjects.description, 
Subjects.unit, COUNT(Enlistment.off_CODE) FROM Enlistment, Subjects
WHERE Subjects.off_CODE = 11315
GROUP BY Enlistment.off_CODE, Subjects.off_CODE
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You are telling the query to GROUP BY a column that you are not selecting. You will need to make sure that you SELECT the columns that are contained within the GROUP BY field.

@Question3CPO's would work except that it includes Subjects.subj_CODE in the SELECT statement and that is probably not contained within the function.