# Selecting data from two different tables without using joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got `table1` and `table2` and need to get data out from each of them.

**Table1**

```
"id"    "name"      "description"
"1"     "Windows"   "Microsoft Windows 8"
```

**Table2**

```
"id" "type" "name"              "description"
"1"  "22"   "Microsoft Windows" "Microsoft Windows 8 Home"
"2"  "2"    "Not an Edit"       "Not an Edit"
```

I do the select like this

```
select table1.name, table1.description, 
table2.name, table2.description 
from table1,table2 
where table2.id=table1.id and table2.`type`=22;
```

Will using an inner join be quicker or more efficient when selecting some 500+ rows at a time?

I've seen most examples using a inner join to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ANSI vs. non-ANSI SQL JOIN syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599050/ansi-vs-non-ansi-sql-join-syntax)

Comment: I don't know where you are finding examples of inner joins like that. Just use an explicit `INNER JOIN`

Comment: You are using a JOIN in your example query, just using deprecated syntax.

Comment: Quicker or more efficient than what? That IS an INNER JOIN; it's just written 'funny'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this..

```
select table1.name, table1.description, 
table2.name, table2.description 
from table1 inner join Table2 on  table2.id=table1.id and table2.`type`=22
```

Answer (score 5):

No difference, just a syntax difference, internally they yield the same execution plan:

[ANSI vs. non-ANSI SQL JOIN syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599050/ansi-vs-non-ansi-sql-join-syntax)

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct answer without join

```
select t1.*,t2.* from t1,t2 where t1.id=t2.id;
```

Comment: Comma is cross join. (With lower precedence than keyword joins.) Also this doesn't answer the question. Also this query doesn't return what the query in the question does.