# Multiple SELECT subqueries to the same table into one

Tags: mysql, sql, myisam

There's a table `message` and a table `sender`, and I want to retrieve all "message information" associated to a specific id, along with the sender name and email. I have this query:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.subject,
    a.body,
    a.sender_id,
    (
        SELECT b.name
        FROM sender b
        WHERE b.id = a.sender_id
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS sender_name,
    (
        SELECT b.email
        FROM sender b
        WHERE b.id = a.sender_id
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS sender_email,
    a.sent_time
FROM message a
WHERE a.id = <id>
LIMIT 1;
```

It works, but it has to perform two different SELECT subqueries *to the same table*.
In this case (which is an extremely simplified example) it probably doesn't hurt the performance at all, but in a real-life scenario where *a lot* of fields have to be retrieved from an external table, the best way to do it is using a JOIN statement? Isn't it possible to have a SELECT subquery that retrieves many fields?

I'm using [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) with [MyISAM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-storage-engine.html) storage engine in case it matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just join to the `sender` tables once in the `FROM` clause.

```
SELECT  a.id,
        a.subject,
        a.body,
        a.sender_id,
        b.name,
        b.email,
        a.sent_time
FROM    message a
INNER JOIN
        sender b
ON      b.id = a.sender_id       
WHERE a.id = <id>
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I thought doing a JOIN was overkill in this case, but I guess it's the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.subject,
    a.body,
    a.sender_id,
    b.name AS sender_name,
    b.email AS sender_email,
    a.sent_time
FROM message a, sender b
WHERE a.id = <id>
AND b.id = a.sender_id
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Please don't recommend non-ANSI JOIN patterns. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1599201/2324286

Comment: @Declan_K If you'd like to keep with the link you gave: "all modern query tools will generate ANSI-92".  The system will automatically transfer one into the other in most cases.  If this syntax is easier, then by all means you are free to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to use a join, you could use [concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) in your subquery `CONCAT(b.name,";",b.email)` and later explode the result on `;` - but I'd go for join :D