# SQL selecting from two tables

Tags: sql, join

What is the difference between ?

```
SELECT u.id,u.name,u.email,d.city,d.state 
from users u, userdetails d 
where u.id=d.uid

SELECT u.id,u.name,u.email,d.city,d.state 
from users u join userdetails d on u.id=d.uid
```

Are they both different style of writing join ? which one  is faster ?

Comment: the first is ansi 86 syntax and the second is ansi 92, look 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599050/ansi-vs-non-ansi-sql-join-syntax

Comment: @今草顿웃 How do you know that a question is duplicate? Do u search stackoverflow for questions resembling this one or one with higher rep has some options where they get a hint that this may be duplicate?

Comment: i have bookmarked this page long time ago `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
SELECT u.id,u.name,u.email,d.city,d.state 
FROM users u, userdetails d
```

Is [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) (the set of all ordered pairs).

When you add the where clause:

```
SELECT u.id,u.name,u.email,d.city,d.state 
FROM users u, userdetails d 
WHERE u.id=d.uid
```

You get [Join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) (combining fields from two tables by using values common to each), which is equivalent to:

```
SELECT u.id,u.name,u.email,d.city,d.state 
FROM users u join userdetails d on u.id=d.uid
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to go for the joining option as it gives you more control, look in to the different types of join (Inner, Left etc) and you can work out exactly what you need for your example.

(I suspect Inner would be best)

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

The variables may not have the same name in each data set, so a natural join can’t be used. 
It is also quite possible to join more than two tables in the same statement. You can even do
transformations and conditional logic.

Answer (score 0):

The two options do the same, but the second is an improved syntax (ANSI SQL-92) and the first is a syntax oldest. Whenever your database system used allows, it is better to use the syntax of the second option.