# What are the difference between these two SQL queries?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, inner-join

What are the differences between these two SQL queries?

Query #1:

```
select mytab.name, mytab.age, films.title, films.author 
from films, mytab 
where films.id = mytab.id;
```

Query #2:

```
select mytab.name, mytab.age, films.title, films.author 
from films inner join mytab 
on films.id = mytab.id;
```

First is a normal SQL query using 'where' statement. The second is using inner join. The result of both queries is exactly the same.

```
films -> id, title author
mytab -> id, name, age
```

It`s the poorest example as is possible.

Here is analogical example :
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: Please note that there is no difference in execution speed, because people sure seem to worry about that a lot.

Comment: They are equivalent and (should) result in identical query plans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Queries will yield same results but the only difference is in syntax,

1st query uses old syntax for join where you describe the relation in `WHERE` clause .

2nd Query uses newer ANSI syntax, where relation between tables are defined in `ON` clause.

Second syntax is preferred though.

[Read Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599050/ansi-vs-non-ansi-sql-join-syntax) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

They are logically equivalent, and will produce the same results.

The first uses older join syntax.

Second uses the ANSI-92 join syntax, and is the preferred style.