# SQL Difference Between WHERE and ON for Joins

Tags: mysql, sql

When using JOINS we have the choice of using either the WHERE clause and the OR clause.

Question: is there a performance difference between these two? Should one be used over the other? What is the difference exactly?

Example:

```
SELECT field 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.id;
```

or

```
SELECT field 
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.id = table2.id;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599050/ansi-vs-non-ansi-sql-join-syntax

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354070/sql-join-where-clause-vs-on-clause

Answer (score 2):

In an `INNER JOIN`, you could use the `ON` and `WHERE` interchangebly, just a case of preference really. The underlying logic doesn't change and it also doesn't have an impact of the execution plan as well.

Its quite different for the `OUTER JOINs`.

a. Filter Criteria in the `WHERE` Clause i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM A left join B
ON A.id=B.id
WHERE B.id=1
```

The above query will function like an `INNER JOIN` and limit the entire result only to the row with B.id=1 (Note that the filter is applied to the table on the right of the `LEFT JOIN` operator)

b. Filter Criteria in the `ON` Clause i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM A left join B
ON A.id=B.id
AND B.id=1
```

The above query will only limit the rows of table B as they are being mapped to `table A` in the `LEFT JOIN` operator. So the result will contain all rows of `table A` and values in the columns for `table B` only for the rows that match the condition `B.id=1`

Credit to @Abraham - here is the [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c7b2f/4) for the same

Answer (score 1):

The performance should the same, but I would prefer the explicit join syntax for any new development.

Answer (score 1):

There are some things you can't do the older `table1, table2` syntax that you can do with the newer `table1 join table2` syntax. Also, for queries involving several tables, the older syntax is incredibly difficult to read.