# How to get the data as follows from the following tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

There are two tables

Table **acctsmem**:

```
E_CODE     E_NAME    E_DEPT
123456     chandu     it
```

Table **acctsdata**:

```
E_CODE     OBJ         SCORE   STATUS
123456     get data      1     FILLED
```

I want data as:

```
E_CODE   E_NAME    E_DEPT    STATUS
123456   chandu    it        FILLED
```

Comment: Um, `join`...  Pretty straight-forward...

Comment: You learn SQL. Are people unable to teach themselves now-a-days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use join, but try the query below. It can work as well..

```
select a.e_code, a.e_name, a.e_dept, b.status
from acctsmem a, acctsdata b where a.e_code = b.e_code;
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599050/ansi-vs-non-ansi-sql-join-syntax

Answer (score 2):

Use `join` to join the tables:

```
select t1.E_CODE,E_NAME,E_DEPT,STATUS from acctsmem t1 join acctsdata t2 on t1.E_CODE = t2.ECODE
```