# Compute the total amount of fee received by school

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

I am using phpMYAdmin, and I fail to compute the total amount of fee received by school.

FeeTable

```
Status     FeeReceived
Yes         100
No          200
```

RegTable

```
Status     School
Yes        A
Yes        B
No         C
No         C
No         C
No         D
No         E
No         E
No         E
Yes        A
Yes        A
Yes        F
Yes        F
Yes        F
Yes        F
No         G
Yes        H
Yes        H
No         I
No         J
No         K
No         L
```

I can only compute the total fee for either Status=Yes or Status=No.

Comment: could you explain the scenario better please?

Comment: For FeeTable, If person's Status is Yes, s/he is charged $100. Otherwise, s/he is charged $200.
RegTable records the Status and School of a person.
I want to compute the total fee received for each school.
=>
$300 from School A
$100 from School B
$600 from School C
$200 from School D
.....
.....
.....
..... and so on.
@MicheleLaFerla

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want a total for yes and a total for no then

```
SELECT Sum(f.FeeReceived) As FeeReceived, r.Status FROM RegTable r JOIN FeeTable f ON f.Status = r.Status GROUP BY r.Status
```

If you want it by status in school:

```
SELECT Sum(f.FeeReceived) As FeeReceived, r.Status, r.School FROM RegTable r JOIN FeeTable f ON f.Status = r.Status GROUP BY r.Status , r.School
```

Total by school:

```
  SELECT Sum(f.FeeReceived) As FeeReceived, r.School FROM RegTable r JOIN FeeTable f ON f.Status = r.Status GROUP BY  r.School
```

Comment: Thanks for your answering!
My question may be unclear, lets me explain the scenario. For FeeTable, If person's Status is Yes, s/he is charged $100. Otherwise, s/he is charged $200. RegTable records the Status and School of a person. I want to compute the total fee received for each school. => $300 from School A $100 from School B $600 from School C $200 from School D ..... ..... ..... ..... and so on. 
@Fred  Thanks for your help again!

Comment: @Fiona try the third one ive just added

Comment: Can you tell me what are the meaning of "f" and "r"? Thanks! @Fred

Comment: Yes, they are just an alias for the table name.  So if you don't alias the table like this `RegTable r` in the query you put `RegTable.Status`. `RegTable r` is like giving it a nickname so you can reference it without typing the fullname.  If a field in your query appears in more than one table you must tell SQL which table you want to take the data from. Always typing `Tablename.FieldName` is a good habit to get into.

Comment: Reason for the downvote? People should really be forced to give a reason. A simple downvote is no good to anyone!

Comment: I solve the problem! the code is SELECT School,SUM(`FeeReceived`) FROM `Fee`,`Reg` WHERE `Fee`.`Status`=`Reg`.`Status` GROUP BY School. By the way, I didn't not give a down vote. @Fred

Comment: @Fred: downvote is because you answered a bad question that showed no effort put in. I don't believe in encouraging bad questions with answers.

Comment: @Fiona that is the same code as my last answer except: You have used the older join syntax which you should try to come away from IMO (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599050/ansi-vs-non-ansi-sql-join-syntax) and you have not aliased the tables.  Wither way they produce the same results, glad you got there.

Comment: @siride fair enough but the guide says "while voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information."  Nowhere does it say "because you don't agree with people answering bad questions" maybe your downvote is misplaced.