# how to join two tables where second table has condtion

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables like

`shopping_cart_table` and `customer_table`

`shopping_cart_table` has  fields `shoppingcart_id | home_No|`

`customer_table` has fields `shoppingcart_id | status| customer_type|`

I want to get the `home_No` from `shopping_cart_table WHERE (customer_table.status is null OR customer_table.status='Y') AND customer_table.customer_type='X'`

both table can join from `shoppingcart_id`

Comment: Where's your specific problem?

Comment: problem is how to do this

Comment: Sorry if this sounds harsh, but that is really, really basic SQL stuff. I'd suggest you grab a SQL tutorial and work through it.

Comment: I know its a basic one but it doesn't work for me. That's why I asked a help

Comment: Then please post a *complete* example next time. In your case, that would be your current SQL statement plus any error message you might get.

Comment: What does this return `SELECT s.home_No
  FROM shopping_cart_table AS s
 INNER JOIN customer_table AS c
    ON s.shoppingcart_id = c.shoppingcart_id`

Comment: @Matt  It returns some records, But if I put the remaining condition to customer_table, it doesn't return anything

Comment: Can you post up your data for each of the tables, `select * from shopping_cart_table` and `select * from customer_table `

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is just basic.
You can use join & put where conditions.

```
Select a.home_No
  from shopping_cart_table as a
 inner join customer_table as b
    on a.shoppingcart_id = b.shoppingcart_id
 where nvl(b.status,'Y') = 'Y'
   and customer_type='X'
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `b.status IS NOT NULL` rather than `b.status = 'Y'` - `Y` is not null... but `NOT NULL` is not `Y`

Comment: @AK47   This doesn't work. Also you missed one condtion.

Comment: Updated. Sorry It should be b.status is null

Comment: Edited , condition added!

Comment: Oh! I also have changed my answer please take a look

Comment: I like to see the use of ANSI joins

Comment: Doesn't return any record

Comment: Please share sample data

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT sct.home_no 
FROM shopping_cart_table AS sct
, customer_table AS ct 
WHERE sct.shoppingcart_id = ct.shoppingcart_id 
AND (
  ct.status IS NOT NULL 
  OR ct.status = 'Y') 
AND ct.customer_type = 'X'
```

Comment: Non ANSI syntax? that is outdated mate. Please take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599050/ansi-vs-non-ansi-sql-join-syntax

Comment: @Thomas Van Driessche   this returns 0 rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
select home_No 
from shopping_cart_table, customer_table
WHERE shopping_cart_table.shoppingcart_id = customer_table.shoppingcart_id
AND(customer_table.status is not null OR customer_table.status='Y') AND       
customer_table.customer_type='X'
```

But this condition looks a bit strange:

```
(customer_table.status is not null OR customer_table.status='Y')
```

Maybe you'd want to change it for

```
nvl(customer_table.status,'Y')='Y'
```

aqssuming that 'not' was put there by a mistake

Comment: Hi, Yes you are correct. It should be is null. If I use your query it doesn't return any thing.