# sqlalchemy .contains() matches only first element

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following Models/Tables in `falsk-sqlalchemy`.:

```py
class MainTerm(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'main_term'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.String)


terms_in_gzt = db.Table('terms_in_gzt',
    db.Column('gzt_term_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('gzt_term.id')),
    db.Column('gazetteer_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('gazetteer.id')),
)

class Gazetteer(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'gazetteer'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    terms = db.relationship('GztTerm', secondary=terms_in_gzt, backref='gazetteers', lazy='dynamic')

class GztTerm(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'gzt_term'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.String)
```

*I'm currently running sqlite (sqlite version '3.32.3'), but it is later intended to use postgresql. So a solution for postgres would be more important than for sqlite.*

And I have this join query that queries the `text` column of `GztTerm` entries that are associated with `Gazetteer.id == 3`:

```py
joinq = db.session.query(GztTerm.text).join(terms_in_gzt).join(Gazetteer).filter(Gazetteer.id == 3)
joinq.all()
```

With the following result:

```py
[('IBM'), ('Lund'), ('Bluetooth')]
```

When I now call:

```py
binary_expression = MainTerm.text.contains(joinq)
res = db.session.query(MainTerm).filter(binary_expression).all()
```

Then I get only results with the first element **"IBM"**. The results with **"Bluetooth"** or **"Lund"** are missing, even though they are in the database. When I change the query, I always get only results for the first element of the `joinq`.

***So my question is:***
What do I need to change, that my [BinaryExpression](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.BinaryExpression) `MainTerm.text.contains(joinq)` considers all the elements of the `joinq`?

Thanks in advance!

---

*Edit:*

*The following code for constructing the `binary_expression` archives the desired behaviour:*

```
from sqlalchemy import or_
binary_expression = or_(MainTerm.text.contains(text) for text in joinq)
```

*However, this feels more like a hack and is probably not that efficient.* 
*Is there some way to archive the same behaviour without loop only using `sqlalchemy`?*

Comment: What DB are you using?

Comment: Print out the query itself, you might spot a difference in the two ways it's generating the SQL code

Comment: @IljaEverilä I'm using sqlite version '3.32.3'. Could this be different for other DBs?

Comment: @Peter what exactly do you mean by print out?

Comment: As in `query = db.session.query(MainTerm).filter(binary_expression); result = query.all()`. You can print the query object to see the raw SQL behind it.

Comment: @Peter thanks for your reply. I have done that. *(too keep it readable I did not post the data here)* `result` only contains entries with `IBM`, the following rows from `joinq` are ignored. No matter how I change the query, only the first element of `joinq` will be considered by the `contains()` expression.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I tested with postgres. There it does not work att all and I get a `CardinalityViolation: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`. Is this a general limitation for `contains`? The `in_` statement works fine even with postgres. Is there some way to work around this limitation? *(it is intended to later use postgres over sqlite)*

Comment: Ah, I get the issue now you posted the edit. All contains does is something around the lines of `select from <table> where <column> LIKE "%<value>%"`. Perhaps use something like this as inspiration on how to get it working, you may need to set up a subquery - https://stackoverflow.com/a/30889878/2403000

Comment: In case of PostgreSQL you could use `LIKE ANY`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42573552/2681632

Comment: @IljaEverilä Thanks for the suggestion! I tried but without luck, I can construct the expression: `binary_expression = MainTerm.text.contains(any_(joinq))` but when running the final query I get `ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "ANY"
LINE 3: WHERE (main_term.text LIKE '%' || (ANY (SELECT gzt_term.text...` where `ANY` is highlighted here. `.contains()` seems to have problems with `any_`,  running the same expression with `like` or `ilike` instead works perfectly fine. *(even though `contains` seems to be a variant of `like`)*

Comment: @IljaEverilä I ended up adding a `column_property('%'+text+'%')` and using `like` instead. This is good enough for me. Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up adding a [`column_property`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-column-property) to `GztTerm`:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import column_property

class GztTerm(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'gzt_term'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.String)
    text_like = column_property('%'+text+'%')
```

This enables me to use [`like`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.like) instead of [`contains`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.contains) (which itself is based on [`like`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.like)) together with [`any_`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.any_) *(Thanks to [Ilja Everilä](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2681632/ilja-everil%C3%A4) for this idea!)*.

The final query looks like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import any_
joinq  = db.session.query(GztTerm.text_like).join(terms_in_gzt).join(Gazetteer).filter(Gazetteer.id == 3)
binary_expression = MainTerm.text.like(any_(joinq))
res = db.session.query(MainTerm).filter(binary_expression).all()
```

To get the complement [`notlike`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.notlike) and [`all_`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.all_) is used for the binary expression:

```
from sqlalchemy import all_
binary_expression = MainTerm.text.notlike(all_(joinq))
```

Hopefully this is helpful to someone!