# SQL Server join - Working clarification

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone explain why one of the joins is done simply comma-separated? Is there any advantage using it like this? What's the meaning of that join, how to rewrite the query by splitting that join as normal joins?

```
select distinct 
    aspl.AssessmentId, TestingProviderId, aspl.AssessmentSubjectId, 
    ep.providername, asplg.PerformanceLevelId as PerformanceLevelId, 
    asplg.PerformanceLevelName, asplg.PerformanceLevelColorARGB, 
    null as PerformanceLevelIdCount, null as GroupTotalCount, 
    null as PercentOfGroup, aspl.LastLoadTime 
from 
    AssessmentStudentPerformanceLevel aspl
inner join 
    AssessmentStudentImported asi on aspl.AssessmentStudentCode = asi.AssessmentStudentCode
inner join 
    EducationProvider ep on asi.testingepid=ep.providerid 
left join 
    Student stu on asi.MappedStudentId = stu.StudentId, 
    AssessmentPerformanceLevelGeneric asplg
where 
    aspl.AssessmentId = asplg.AssessmentId 
    and aspl.testingproviderid = ep.providerid 
    and ((IsNull(null, 0) = 0) or (ep.providerid = null))
    and ((IsNull(0, 0) = 0) or (ep.providerlevelid = 0))
    and aspl.AssessmentId = 239012015 
    and aspl.assessmentsubjectid = 1 
order by 
    aspl.AssessmentId, aspl.AssessmentSubjectId, 
    ep.providername, asplg.PerformanceLevelId
```

In the above query, I mentioned this section

```
 left join 
     Student stu on asi.MappedStudentId = stu.StudentId, 
     AssessmentPerformanceLevelGeneric asplg
```

Comment: That one is an old-join syntax, which should be avoided. Read more [here](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ANSI vs. non-ANSI SQL JOIN syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599050/ansi-vs-non-ansi-sql-join-syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AssessmentPerformanceLevelGeneric` is a table with `asplg` is alias name.

Comma ',' with condition is inner join, without condition is cross join.

```
SELECT *
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON <condition>
=
SELECT *
FROM A, B
WHERE <condition>


SELECT *
FROM A
CROSS JOIN B
=
SELECT *
FROM A, B
```

Comment: I'm not saying about alias  ,i wanted the working of that old joining style,how that works with which field joining conditions comes etc,Thank you.

Comment: Will that  be with the primarykey column of the from table?