# SQL Distinct Sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, northwind

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    E.FirstName + ' ' + E.LastName [Full Name], 
    P.ProductName, 
    OD.Quantity
FROM    Employees E, 
        Products P, 
        [Order Details] OD, 
        Orders O
WHERE 
    E.EmployeeID = O.EmployeeID
    AND O.OrderID = OD.OrderID
    AND OD.ProductID = P.ProductID
```

In the Northwind gives back duplicate `FullNames` and `ProductNames` because of the `Quantity` which is changed (because of the date shipped each time).

I want to present only a Name to a specific `ProductName` with the Total Quantity and not divided.

Comment: You're looking for [`GROUP BY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  And please please please start using [ANSI syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599050/ansi-vs-non-ansi-sql-join-syntax) for joins.

Comment: Why not just leave `Quantity` out of the `SELECT` ?

Comment: @BJMyers , could you be more specific for that example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP BY` with `SUM`:

```
SELECT
    e.FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName AS [Full Name], 
    p.ProductName, 
    SUM(od.Quantity) AS [Quantity]
FROM Employees e
INNER JOIN Orders o
    ON o.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN [Order Details] od
    ON od.OrderID = o.OrderID
INNER JOIN Products p
    ON p.ProductID = od.ProductID
GROUP BY
    e.FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName,
    p.ProductName
```

Note, you need to [stop using the old-style `JOIN` syntax.](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0):

I think,it was a good question for discussion.

Correct query always depend upon your actual requirement.

I think your table is too much normalise.In such situation most of them will also keep Employeeid in order_detail table.

At the same time,most of them keep sum value in Order table.
Like sum of quantity,sum of amount etc per orderid in order table.

you can also create view without aggregate function joining all the table.

IMHO,Using Group By clause on so many column and that too on varchar column is bad idea.

Try something like this,

```
;With CTE as
(
 SELECT 
    E.FirstName + ' ' + E.LastName [Full Name], 
     O.OrderID,od.qty,P.ProductName
FROM  Employees E
inner join  Orders O on  E.EmployeeID = O.EmployeeID
inner join [Order Details] OD on o.orderid=od.orderid      
inner join [Products] P on p.ProductID=od.ProductID 
)
,CTE1 as
(
select od.orderid, sum(qty) TotalQty 
from CTE c
group by c.orderid

)

select c.[Full Name],c1.TotalQty, P.ProductName from cte c
inner join cte1 c1 on c.orderid=c1.orderid
```