# Difference between these two SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql, join

So I'm testing 2 queries and I'm getting different results. I want to correct/patch up my understanding. Here's two generic SQL queries that to my understanding are the same but **when executed get different results**. Note this is not a question about [diff between ANSI and non-ANSI SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599050/ansi-vs-non-ansi-sql-join-syntax).

Query 1 (using `LEFT JOIN`):

```
SELECT * FROM person p LEFT JOIN person_log pl
ON p.person_id = pl.person_id
WHERE pl.person_id IS NULL
AND p.is_active = 1;
```

---

Query 2 (using 2 queries):

```
SELECT * FROM person
WHERE person.is_active = 1
AND person_id NOT IN (SELECT person_id FROM person_log);
```

To my understanding, both [represent this in venn diagram form](https://blog.codinghorror.com/content/images/uploads/2007/10/6a0120a85dcdae970b012877702754970c-pi.png). Also, is one more efficient than the other? A query on `JOIN` results vs 2 queries?

EDIT: Changed `=` to `IS` in query 1. Thanks to @Justin Samuel for spotting the `=` error that's causing different results!

Comment: Without optimizer stepping in, and on lees advanced DBs, #1 should be faster and scaleable. Optimiser should convert #2 to #1

Comment: Joins can't be correctly represented with venn diagrams, is just a simplified way to explain it visually

Comment: @Bohemian This isn't always true. If there are `NULL`s in the `person_id` column of the `person_log` table, then the results will be completely different

Comment: Agreed they generally are the same thing however as Lamak points wout if person_id coult be null in person_log then you will NOT get your desired results.  NOT EXISTS could be faster than both of these methods. Plus this kind of is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists

Comment: @Matt Your link is for SQL Server, and if I remember correctly in MySQL the `NOT EXISTS` solution is generally slower than the `LEFT JOIN` one

Comment: @Bohemian I can see why but the funny thing is, I'm using Oracle SQL Developer to execute the two queries and query 1 (50~ sec) takes a lot longer than query 2 (1~ sec).

Comment: @lamak I'm made the reasonable assumption that a table called `person_log` that has a column called `person_id` that is a foreign key to the `person` table has no nulls. It there are any nulls (a personless person log entry?), you get no results, which is hardly a subtle difference. Further, if there are nulls, you could add the trivial condition `where person_id is not null` to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both queries get you the same data.

The second query is the straight-forward way to the problem; get all persons that have no entry in person_log. You can do the same with a `NOT EXISTS` clause instead of a `NOT IN` clause. (`NOT IN` is a bit leaner, but the values you select in the subquery must not be null, for otherwise you see no data at all. I usually perfer `IN` / `NOT IN` over `EXISTS` / `NOT EXISTS` for their simplicity, but that's a matter of personal preference.

The first query is called an anti join. It is a trick to achieve the same as a `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN` query on weak database systems that don't implement these methods well. (The reason is that when a new database system is written, the programmers usually put all their effort in joins for they are so important and neglect `EXISTS` and `IN` for some time.)

It depends on the DBMS which gets executed fastest, `NOT IN`, `NOT EXISTS` or the anti join. The ideal DBMS would get to the same execution plan, no matter which syntax you choose.

The anti join can produce large intermediate results. With a mature DBMS you shouldn't use anti joins for this reason and for mere readability.

Answer (score 2):

There is one bug in the above query 1. You cannot use "=" to check whether it is NULL

```
SELECT * FROM person p LEFT JOIN person_log pl
ON p.person_id = pl.person_id
WHERE pl.person_id = NULL
AND p.is_active = 1;
```

Ideally you should be using IS NULL

```
SELECT * FROM person p LEFT JOIN person_log pl
ON p.person_id = pl.person_id
WHERE pl.person_id IS NULL
AND p.is_active = 1;
```

You can review the NULL checks in the https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-get-nulls-horribly-wrong-in-sql-server/

Comment: Oh cool! Because of that change, now both queries return the same and the above answers make more sense. I wish I can have two answers. Maybe some admin can merge your answer with the accepted answer. (if they ever notice this)

Comment: @Sticky - Nice to hear that your issue is resolved. As far as the comparison between the two approaches go it varies based on the situation and specifics like indexing etc etc. So I didnt comment on that part.

Comment: Oops, I missed the part where Sticky told us that the queries don't give the same result. (Well, a question like "why isn't the first query returning any rows" might have been more obvious.) Well spotted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for rows that don't match in the second table, especially if columns are not nullable then use NOT IN.

Comment: This is wrong, if the columns are nullable, then the `NOT IN` shouldn't be used at all

Comment: The optimizer (which only gets better over time) apparently pegs them as identical according to this frequently seen reference [Here](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/). So I see no difference. Obviously queries and schemas vary. But one needs to be scientific about it, not guess.

Comment: I did not think that optimization could determine if a query was for only non existing values. I guess things are getting smarter.

Answer (score 0):

The first one gets all the persons that have no log entries and then filters out the inactive ones.

The second query gets all the persons. Then filters out the inactive. Then gets all the log entries. Then filters out the persons that have no log entries.

They will both return the same info. However, for performance reasons, queries like the second one should be avoided if using a JOIN is possible. The main benefit of the JOINs is indexes. Only one index in the WHERE will be used, but each JOIN will use one.