# Join two mysql tables with LIKE condition.

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to run this code but i'm getting errors. 
Any ideas why?

```
SELECT notes.project_id, notes.title, notes.description 
FROM notes, project_members 
WHERE notes.title LIKE '%second%' OR notes.description LIKE  '%second%'
WHERE notes.project_id = project_members.project_id AND project_members.user_id = '7'
```

Comment: you have to where clauses.. Concat the conditions with and/or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only can have one `WHERE` clause you could use a inner join like this:

```
SELECT notes.project_id, notes.title, notes.description 
  FROM project_members pm
INNER JOIN notes ON notes.project_id = pm.project_id AND pm.user_id = 7
  WHERE notes.title LIKE '%second%' OR notes.description LIKE '%second%'
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be single `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT notes.project_id, notes.title, notes.description 
FROM notes, project_members 
WHERE 
(notes.title LIKE '%second%' OR notes.description LIKE  '%second%')
AND notes.project_id = project_members.project_id AND project_members.user_id = '7';
```

Query would look something above to **AND** between your **LIKE** conditions.

You may also consider using `JOIN`, Like this.

```
SELECT notes.project_id, notes.title, notes.description 
FROM notes
JOIN project_members
ON notes.project_id=project_members.project_id
WHERE 
    (notes.title LIKE '%second%' OR notes.description LIKE  '%second%')
AND project_members.user_id = '7';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two `WHERE` clauses, but single `SELECT` only allows one.  But, this would *easily* be fixed if you used proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT n.project_id, n.title, n.description 
FROM notes n JOIN
     project_members  p
     ON n.project_id = p.project_id
WHERE (n.title LIKE '%second%' OR n.description LIKE '%second%') AND
      p.user_id = '7';
```

Note:

- *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- I'm pretty sure your `WHERE` conditions are missing parentheses, for your intended logic.
- If `user_id` is a number of any sort, then don't use single quotes around "7".  This can confuse both the compiler and people.

Comment: [Further justification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599050/ansi-vs-non-ansi-sql-join-syntax) of explicit `join`s.