# SQL Multi-Table View Joins

Tags: sql, join

I'm a noobie with SQL and have a syntax problem about multi-table joins.

I checked multi-table join syntax examples and looks like two different type of writing -as shown below- is acceptable.

```
SELECT aaa.x, bbb.y, ccc.z
FROM   aaa, bbb, ccc
```

OR

```
SELECT aaa.x, bbb.y, ccc.z
FROM   aaa, bbb
JOIN   ccc
```

I wonder about what should i use in general multi-table joins, should i seperate tables with JOIN keyword or use all table names in FROM clause and why i should use first or second join syntax, is it just personal or better than another?

Comment: Use the second format - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599050/ansi-vs-non-ansi-sql-join-syntax

Comment: You should use JOIN for all tables after the first. The first syntax you have shown is extremely old and not best practice any more.