# Mysql select query for 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a 3 tables **order, order_option, product_option**

**order**

```
order_id | cus_name | cus_phone
-------------------------------
1        | Test-1   | 9876543211
2        | Test-2   | 9876543212
3        | Test-3   | 9876543213
4        | Test-4   | 9876543214
```

**order_option**

```
product_option_id | order_id 
-------------------------------
11                | 1
12                | 1
13                | 2
14                | 4
15                | 3
```

**product_option**

```
product_id | product_option_id | sku     | qty
------------------------------------------
1          | 11                | TS01    | 3
2          | 12                | TS02    | 2
3          | 13                | TS033   | 3
4          | 14                | TS023   | 3
```

Here I want to select `order` table and `product_option` table values with a where condition on the `sku` field.

i tried to join the query like below:

```
SELECT o.order_id, o.cus_name, o.cus_phone,po.sku,po.qty FROM order o 
LEFT JOIN order_option op 
ON (o.order_id = op.order_id) 
LEFT JOIN product_option po
ON (op.product_option_id = po.product_option_id) 
WHERE po.sku = "TS023"
```

But it's not showing the correct answer. I don't know what I have missed.

Comment: What is it showing now and what do you expect?

Comment: How many records do you expect from your current query?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: more then 100 rows

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I try to get orders list by sku

Comment: I meant from your sample data.  How many rows from your sample data should be returned?

Answer (score 1):

`order` is a reserved word, use backticks ``.

```
SELECT o.order_id, o.cus_name, o.cus_phone, po.sku, po.qty 
FROM `order` o 
LEFT JOIN order_option op ON o.order_id = op.order_id
LEFT JOIN product_option po ON op.product_option_id = po.product_option_id
WHERE po.sku = "TS023"
```

Output:

```
order_id    cus_name    cus_phone   sku     qty
4           Test-4      9876543214  TS023   3
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b76b/2/0

Comment: @RameshS Doubt about?

Comment: Select order list who purchase `sku = TS023`

Comment: What is the query ?

Answer (score 1):

Move the po condition from `WHERE` to `ON` to get true `LEFT JOIN` result:

```
SELECT o.order_id, o.cus_name, o.cus_phone,po.sku,po.qty FROM order o 
LEFT JOIN order_option op 
ON (o.order_id = op.order_id) 
LEFT JOIN product_option po
ON (op.product_option_id = po.product_option_id) 
AND po.sku = "TS023"
```

(When in WHERE, you'll get regular INNER JOIN result.)

Answer (score 0):

@Matt is correct, here's another way of doing this.

```
SELECT o.order_id, o.cus_name, o.cus_phone, po.sku, po.qty 
FROM `order` o, order_option op, product_option po
WHERE o.order_id = op.order_id
AND op.product_option_id = po.product_option_id
AND po.sku = "TSO23"
```

Comment: Don't join tables like that, you should use ANSI compliant joins.

Comment: @Matt it's just another way of doing it. I agree the ANSI joins should be used but it doesn't make it less correct. Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599050/ansi-vs-non-ansi-sql-join-syntax

Comment: Oracle explicitly advises to use ANSI compliant joins.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: @jarlh I know, if you'd read my comment ^^ But for simple queries I tend to use the old version.