# QueryExecute(): How to use SQL wildcard % search with a LIKE clause?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, coldfusion-2016

I am new to ColdFusion and am trying to query something and use it in the cfscript.  I cannot use actual code here, but here is a general SQL query I hope will help.  It's a old script and I am trying to change it from cfquery tags to cfscript tags.

```
<cfscript>
    sqlCF = queryExecute("SELECT primarykey FROM names, personnel  
                          WHERE name.primaykey = personnel.primarykey 
                          AND ( upper(personnel.ID LIKE upper(':id%') OR 
                                upper(personnel.userID) LIKE upper(':id%')
                              )
                        , {id={value = "xyz123", cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar}}
                        , {datasource=person"}); 

writeDump(sqlCF);
</cfscript>
```

When I run it, it shows up as 0 queries, but when I hard code it in and change the `:id%` part of the query to `xyz123%` as the value it works.  I just do not know how the LIKE('XXXX%'), with a wild card sign, should be passed or if this even looks right.  Any ideas?

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but if you're updating old code, may as well change to the newer [ANSI-99 JOIN syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599050/ansi-vs-non-ansi-sql-join-syntax) as well.

Answer (score 6):

You want to append the wildcard symbol to the string in your parameter, not inside your query string. Also notice when I used parameters, I'm not wrapping the parameters in quotes.

```
<cfscript>
    sqlCF = queryExecute("
        select primarykey
        from names, personnel
        where name.primaykey = personnel.primarykey
        and (
            upper(personnel.ID) LIKE upper(:id)
            or 
            upper(personnel.userID) LIKE upper(:id)
        )
    ",{
        id={
            value = "xyz123%",
            cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"
        }
    },
    {datasource="person"});
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Darn, beat me to it!  Also, the datasource name should be enclosed in quotes: `datasource="person"`.

Comment: True if its a string and not a variable. There were quite a few syntax issues with the posted example in regards to were quotes started and stoped, so I had to guess what should/shouldn't be quoted.

Comment: Yep. I only know because I tested it with a different query, and CF complained about the lack of quotes.

Comment: I'm not a fan of it, but the applications I maintain are littered with `datasource=session.dsn`; so my mind opted for no quotes. I agree the quotes look better here.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. That works because it's a variable. (It doesn't in the OP's case because the name is a string literal, so CF looks for a variable named "person" and errors when it doesn't find one).

Comment: Thanks guys!.  You guys helped me out!  I totally was not thinking the putting the wildcard in the parameter.  I should of thought outside of my box and changed the query.