# SQL Server 2016 virtual tables - Incorrect syntax 'AS'

Tags: sql-server

Assuming a table `level` with columns `level_id` and `level_name`

I have a virtual table in my SQL Server 2016 query:

This is not a real query - I've simplified it as much as possible to illustrate the error

```
SELECT
    LEVEL .level_id,
    LEVEL .level_name
FROM
    LEVEL,
    ((SELECT
          LEVEL_ID AS lev_sum_level_id
      FROM
          LEVEL
      GROUP BY
          level_id) AS lev_sum
     JOIN
         (SELECT
              LEVEL_ID AS lev_det_level_id
          FROM
              LEVEL
          GROUP BY
              level_id) AS lev_det ON (lev_sum_level_id = lev_det_level_id)
  ) AS totals
```

The syntax error is on the line `AS totals`.

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 35
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'

Why is SQL Server not allowing this syntax? Seems fine if I simplify the virtual table query. Postgres allows it as-is

Comment: Did you try it without the `AS totals` alias?  T-sql and postgresql aren't interchangeable, and your syntax is pretty funky. You should really be using ANSI-95 SQL syntax in SQL Server. For further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599050/ansi-vs-non-ansi-sql-join-syntax

Comment: the query doesn't look valid

Comment: it looks like the query should add a select. as you are just joined two tables together but it didn't provide what should extract from the dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try to add a select so that you can complete the syntax of the statement

Please try

```
SELECT
T1.MiscID,
T2.lev_sum_level_id
FROM
Miscs AS T1,
(
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT
            MiscID AS lev_sum_level_id
        FROM
            Miscs
        GROUP BY
            MiscID
    ) AS lev_sum
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            MiscID AS lev_det_level_id
        FROM
            Miscs
        GROUP BY
            MiscID
    ) AS lev_det 
    ON( lev_sum_level_id = lev_det_level_id )
) AS T2
```

Comment: thanks.  Seems Postgres infers this, whereas MSSQL does not